# Google Cloud Vision Training

Tags: artificial-intelligence, vision

Is there any way how to train Google's vision [TEXT] on specific pictures?
For example: add more pictures to get clear text recognition.

Comment: Please elaborate the problem? Ask specific questions, Tell us what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: We are working on the project where we need to grab numbers from the display, for example, this picture [sample picture](http://indianapublicmedia.org/news/files/2013/05/digital-parking-meter.jpg)

Comment: ok! But what did you try out? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I was trying google vision with text recognition.

Comment: all we need to get numbers (time) in JSON